# Calculate difference between max date and selected date

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4cce04619b66cb584273a979ebf08792)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp_inventory TIMESTAMP,
    product_name VARCHAR(255),
    product_value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO inventory (timestamp_inventory, product_name, product_value)
VALUES ('2020-01-28 05:03:20', 'Product_A', '400'),
       ('2020-01-29 06:08:30', 'Product_A', '300'),
       ('2020-01-30 17:15:29', 'Product_A', '500'),
       ('2020-01-31 15:01:03', 'Product_A', '800'),
       ('2020-02-01 17:08:21', 'Product_A', '600'),
       ('2020-02-09 19:05:08', 'Product_A', '700'),

       ('2020-01-31 09:50:23', 'Product_B', '300'),
       ('2020-02-05 00:00:10', 'Product_B', '200'),
       ('2020-02-15 23:07:59', 'Product_B', '900');
```

Expected result:

```
product_name    |  days_in_inventory   |
----------------+----------------------+
Product_A       |        20            |
Product_B       |        14            |
```

I want to calculate the difference of `days` between `'2020-02-29 23:59:59'` and the `MAX(timestamp_inventory)`.

In **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=286c8a98e934e7579303124c5b252509)** I got the expected result and tried to transfer the query to PostgresSQL:

```
SELECT
    iv.product_name,
    iv.timestamp_inventory,
    DATE_PART('day', MAX(iv.timestamp_inventory)::date) - DATE_PART('day', '2020-02-29 23:59:59'::date) AS days_in_inventory,
    iv.product_value
FROM 
    inventory iv
GROUP BY 
    1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY 
    1, 2, 3, 4;
```

However, with this query I get error

> ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
>
> LINE 4: DATE_PART('day', MAX(iv.timestamp_inventory)::date) - DATE_P...

How do I need to modify the query to get the expected result?

Comment: Grouping by all columns of the select (including the aggregate functions) never makes sense to begin with. Including the `timestamp_inventory` makes even less sense as that results in one group per row as all values are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just subtract the dates directly:

```sql
SELECT
    product_name,
    '2020-02-29'::date - MAX(timestamp_inventory::date) AS days_in_inventory
FROM inventory
GROUP BY
    product_name
ORDER BY
    product_name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo